# Wrong connection port despite Kubernetes deployments/services ports specified

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

It might take a while to explain what I'm trying to do but bear with me please.

I have the following infrastructure specified:
[image]

I have a job called `questo-server-deployment` (I know, confusing but this was the only way to access the deployment without using ingress on minikube)

This is how the parts should talk to one another:
[image]

And [here](https://github.com/matewilk/questo/pull/8/files#diff-a9b6f2819e0e34608760f562298832266b7da1a55cb004d9cdc7e2dc8c6d6e54) you can find the entire Kubernetes/Terraform config file for the above setup

I have 2 endpoints exposed from the `node.js` app (`questo-server-deployment`)
I'm making the requests using `10.97.189.215` which is the `questo-server-service` external IP address (as you can see in the first picture)

So I have 2 endpoints:

- health - which simply returns `200 OK` from the `node.js` app - and this part is fine confirming the node app is working as expected.
- dynamodb - which should be able to send a request to the `questo-dynamodb-deployment` (pod) and get a response back, but it can't.

When I print env vars I'm getting the following:

```
➜ kubectl -n minikube-local-ns exec questo-server-deployment--1-7ptnz -- printenv
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=questo-server-deployment--1-7ptnz
DB_DOCKER_URL=questo-dynamodb-service
DB_REGION=local
DB_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=local
DB_TABLE_NAME=Questo
DB_ACCESS_KEY=local
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT_4000_TCP=tcp://10.97.189.215:4000
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT_4000_TCP_PORT=4000
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=8000
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT_8000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT_8000_TCP_PORT=8000
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_HOST=10.96.0.1
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PORT=443
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR=10.96.0.1
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.97.189.215
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.97.189.215:4000
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT_4000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_PORT_4000_TCP_ADDR=10.97.189.215
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_PROTO=tcp
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT_8000_TCP=tcp://10.107.45.125:8000
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT_8000_TCP_ADDR=10.107.45.125
KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP=tcp://10.96.0.1:443
QUESTO_SERVER_SERVICE_SERVICE_PORT=4000
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_SERVICE_HOST=10.107.45.125
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT=tcp://10.107.45.125:8000
KUBERNETES_SERVICE_PORT_HTTPS=443
NODE_VERSION=12.22.7
YARN_VERSION=1.22.15
HOME=/root
```

so it looks like the configuration is aware of the dynamodb address and port:

```
QUESTO_DYNAMODB_SERVICE_PORT_8000_TCP=tcp://10.107.45.125:8000
```

You'll also notice in the above env variables that I specified:

```
DB_DOCKER_URL=questo-dynamodb-service
```

Which is supposed to be the `questo-dynamodb-service` url:port which I'm assigning to the config [here](https://github.com/matewilk/questo/pull/8/files#diff-a9b6f2819e0e34608760f562298832266b7da1a55cb004d9cdc7e2dc8c6d6e54R163) (in the configmap) which is then used [here](https://github.com/matewilk/questo/pull/8/files#diff-a9b6f2819e0e34608760f562298832266b7da1a55cb004d9cdc7e2dc8c6d6e54R67) in the `questo-server-deployment` (job)

Also, when I log:

```
kubectl logs -f questo-server-deployment--1-7ptnz -n minikube-local-ns
```

I'm getting the following results:

[image]

Which indicates that the app (node.js) tried to connect to the db (dynamodb) but on the wrong port `443` instead of `8000`?

The `DB_DOCKER_URL` should contain the full address (with port) to the `questo-dynamodb-service`

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit ----

I've explicitly assigned the port `8000` to the `DB_DOCKER_URL` as suggested in the answer but now I'm getting the following error:
[image]

Seems to me there is some kind of default behaviour in Kubernetes and it tries to communicate between pods using `https` ?

Any ideas what needs to be done here?

Answer (score 2):

How about specify the port in the ConfigMap:

```
...
data = {
  DB_DOCKER_URL = ${kubernetes_service.questo_dynamodb_service.metadata.0.name}:8000
...
```

Otherwise it may default to 443.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking time to answer, I've updated the question with another issue, seems to me the pods are trying to communicate using `https` protocol? From the error after applying your suggestion, it seems like the pod is trying to find an `ssl` cert which obviously doesn't exist. It would also explain why it was trying to use `443` in the first place. Is there any way to tell Kubernetes to use http only?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question in case anyone have an equally brilliant idea of running `local dybamodb` in a `minikube` cluster.

The issue was not only with the `port`, but also with the `protocol`, so the final answer to the question is to modify the `ConfigMap` as follows:

```
data = {
    DB_DOCKER_URL = "http://${kubernetes_service.questo_dynamodb_service.metadata.0.name}:8000"
    ...
}
```

---

As a side note:

Also, when you are running various scripts to create a `dynamodb` table in your `amazon/dynamodb-local` container, make sure you use the same `region` for both creating the table like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

aws dynamodb create-table \
    --cli-input-json file://questo_db_definition.json \
    --endpoint-url http://questo-dynamodb-service:8000 \
    --region local
```

And the same `region` when querying the data.

Even though this is just a local copy, where you can type anything you want as a value of your `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` and actually in the `AWS_REGION` as well, the `region` have to match.

If you query the db with a different `region` it was created with, you get the `Cannot do operations on a non-existent table` error.